# Sorting within another sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a set of data that has multiple properties, and the primary way I want them sorted is having item B after item A, but I don't want to affect the order of those items outside of that.

Dataset (in no particular order):

- record 1
- record 2
- record 3 (has Item A property)
- record 4
- record 5 (item A)

Dataset (sorted by item A)

- record 1
- record 2
- record 4
- record 5 (item A)
- record 3 (has Item A property)

My goal is to sort whatever has the "item A property" after the actual "item A". I'm blanking on how to make sure it's always sorted below the other item, regardless of what order each item returns.

I'm trying to do this within a JavaScript sort function, if possible.

Here's another example as well:

Dataset (in no particular order):

- record 1
- record 2 (item A)
- record 3
- record 4
- record 5 (has Item A property)

Dataset (sorted by item A)

- record 1
- record 2 (item A)
- record 5 (has Item A property)
- record 3
- record 4

Comment: You could filter this into two lists: one list of items without A and one list of items with A, but leaving "item A" itself in the original list. Then sort the 'items with A' list on property B. Then insert the sorted list back into the "items without A" list after the location of "item A".

Comment: do you have always two item who you wants to sort together?

Comment: @jarmod Thanks, that's the solution I had to take in order to sort them properly

Answer (score 0):

You could map the items and for the wanted group take an array. later flat the result.

```js
const
    array = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'aa', 'a'],
    group = [],
    result = array
        .map(v => {
            if (v === 'a') {      // first item
                group.unshift(v);
                return group;
            }
            if (v === 'aa') {     // connected item
                group.push(v);
                return [];
            }
            return v;
        })
        .flat();

console.log(...result);
```